# Typescript - pass a function and its arguments to another function & enforce number and types of args

Tags: typescript

I want to define a function that gets as parameters another function `f` and its arguments `args`, and I want Typescript to make sure that the passed arguments are correct for the passed function.

Pseudo code

```
function A (n: number, s: string, b: boolean) {
  ...
}

function B (f: Function, ...args: typeof arguments of f) {
  ...
  f(args)
}

B(A, 1, 'str', true) // typescript is happy
B(A, 1, 'str') // typescript is sad
B(A, 1, undefined, true) // typescript is sad
// any other example of wrong arguments of A passed to b would raise Typescript error...
```

So the important part here is this:

```
...args: typeof arguments of f
```

Which is obviously **not** valid Typescript.

How can I write typescript code that does that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can do that using the [Parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) utility type.

For example...

```
function B<T extends (...args: any) => any> (f: T, ...args: Parameters<T>) {
  f(args)
}
```

[Here is a playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&q=355#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQUQCjALkWEBbAIwFMAnAGkQGdtKoSYwBzCg7AuOAGyIEMwBKRAG8AsACgAvuPGhIsBIgBCAHgAqiIgA8oRMABNK6AHQmeJRtUR8AnoIC8APithrTtMGyqKJo2YvYABTMePCIdEko1B0FRMUREYDQ-Sn5xKTFxRTRkCgBGCgByWhICijoQIkEAeirEKGsAByJKCHoGqEQYQwALHgaG60zsvMLigura%20qaWto6uqh49IZzEfMRwPSJgBiI9MpIKibrG5taYds7DSkXpMRrna0Q4KG7SDU0Qhu4n4EQAdxICEYVnM%20F0UEMcF%20qAaPEolF2dTgiAI-zgIE4ekQJB4XSIiFUJxm5w6pEBJBMQA) showing the errors you are expecting.

Note that this checking is compile time only and will not provide any runtime protection after the TypeScript is compiles to JavaScript. If you need runtime protection you need to use the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object and write some custom code to verify number and types of arguments passed. Something like [this](https://blog.dezfowler.com/2008/08/function-overloading-in-javascript.html).